# What is the chronological list of D&D 3(.5)e material?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, publishing

The ring of the darkhidden wondrous item has been published in both MoF and MIC. I assume Magic of Faerûn was printed before Magic Item Compendium, but I want to know for sure. There is a similar [question for 4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/comprehensive-list-of-wotc-dd-4-0-products), so why not 3(.5)e?
The reason that I say 3(.5)e instead of 3e or 3.5e is because some people are willing to allow/use (unupdated) 3e material in their 3.5e game, and [some products-released-close-to-the-release-of-3.5e can be described as 3.25e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1142/7980), like Savage Species and Book of Vile Darkness. I am particularly interested in 3.5e.
The reason that I say "material" is I don't assume that all crunch/rules/mechanics (and things that may-be-more-fluff-but-may-have-an-effect-on-crunch) were printed in books. For example, magazines and web articles may not be considered books.

So, can we have a chronological list of 3(.5)e material?

Comment: [Here's a list of actual printed texts in order of publication](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610), but there are *at least* 321 *Dungeons and Dragons 3.X* articles on the Wizards of the Coast Web site and countless magazine articles. I fear this is too broad.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't think it's too broad, there's a 4e version of the same question and what the question asks for is specific enough. The problem is that any good answer would have to be so huge that I don't think anyone will ever do it.

Comment: @Tridus The Too Broad Close vote includes excluding "good answers [that] would be too long for this format." I'll happily retract my vote if some dude posts his 1,000-or-so-entry chronological list of all *D&D 3.X* material. And, if he gives me his IRL address, I'll mail him $20 because whoever did such a thing needs more than just Internet praise for his efforts.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ah, good point. :)

Comment: Regardless of whether or not a list is on-topic or not, this question is answered, effectively, by @HeyICanChan's list in the 3.0 vs. 3.5 question. Someone who *actually wants to produce* a more-comprehensive list can and should do it there.

Comment: We don't do CW any more like the old 4e question.  This question is licit if answered with a link to a resource that provides this information, but we probably shouldn't do it here.