# Does there exist a complete list of D&D 3.X Wizards of the Coast Web site articles?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, online-resources

The Wizards of the Coast Web site has some buried *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* and *3.5* articles like [this](https://ww2.wizards.com/books/mirrorstone/Article.aspx?doc=fr_baenre2) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20141222093838/https://ww2.wizards.com/books/mirrorstone/Article.aspx?doc=dl_magicitems).<sup>1</sup> The usual site's [article categories](https://web.archive.org/web/20200314182849/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/retired) omit some categories, especially regarding campaign settings (e.g. the Eberron columns [Clockwork Wonders](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031222520/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/archeb/cw) and [Adventure Seeds](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101190541/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/archeb/as)) and, of course, standalone pieces (e.g. ["New Magic Items,"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125024806/http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/MagicItems.pdf) ["Dead Life,"](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101074900/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/dx20021031x) ["Donations and Interventions,"](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101074616/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=fr/fx20020424x) ["Ecology of a Dragon's Hoard"](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205204/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20060811a)). And even the [archives by year](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112033730/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/dnd) are incomplete (e.g. the article ["Priest of the Moons Mage Hunter Prestige Class"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126100910/http://www.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?X=dl/lx20001205b) is undoubtedly from shortly after the publication of *Third Edition*, but it isn't archived;  unlisted for [2003](https://web.archive.org/web/20170615215630/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/2003) is the April Fools Web article ["Fabulous Cats!"](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112022038/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fools/20030401c)).

Thus even if one clicked through the entire archive year by year, one would still miss stuff. That makes me sad.

Now that the game's *two* editions ago, is there a *real* list of, like, *all* the articles on the Wizards of the Coast Web site for *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* and *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*?

***Note:*** *A reasonable answer could include, for example, a more easily navigable and searchable mirror of the site, another site that has a more complete index, or another site with categorized lists of stuff on the Wizards of the Coast site like feats, magic items, and prestige classes. It would be helpful to know what the linked site does well and a summary of that site's resources. (It'll also avoid a link-only answer.)*

*It's possible an answer may include more-than-casual Web-browser functions (looking at a page's source or something... I lack the grammar)--and that's okay--but I* really *don't care about improving my overall browsing experience or anything and, instead, care only about information related to the single site.*

*This question is similar to, but, I think, different* enough *from, this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48258/8610).*

---

1. Playing a caster? Get *Raistlin's frog* (1,000 gp; 0 lbs.). In fact, splurge and get two.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I fixed the URL to the new home of Min Max.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you for updating this question's links. That's an impressive amount of hunting.

Comment: @HeyICanChan you're welcome. Fortunately for me, it's all scripted and I only have to do a few spot checks afterwards :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a [post at minmaxboards](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=513.0) that is a "Guide to Free D&D" so it contains everything posted online by WotC, the SRD and much more in a very organized form.
I cannot know if it is 100% complete given the fact that even the official index on-site has issues but it certain is far easier to navigate and believe it fits your question.
EDIT: as a note thanks to @Mourdos, the link in the aforementioned page does not work as WotC made some changes to their site a while ago. They need to be accessed through an archive page, which the forum's op has provided right at the beginning.

Comment: You might want to add a note that they need to read the second sentence of the first post or none of the links will work. Alternatively, just like directly to the web.archive? (Though I know the author says he might update)